# How do I get around clipping issues with my app in smaller phones?

Tags: android, testing, cross-platform, dimensions, clipping

I have a basic linear layout, with image view that display photos, textviews that show text etc...and when I test my whole app on my android 2, there is never any part of the screen that doesn't show.  But when I test it in the QVGA emulator, half the view is off the screen.  Now, some of my text is defined to a certain size.

I never use px (only dip) in any of my xml.  I use fill_parent, wrap_content where it is needed and never fix a height or length.  Could it be with my text, I use say, textSize = 22dip?  I couldn't find documentation on why that would not work in all sizes.

Could it be that some apps need to be programmed to those screen sizes?  Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIP actually doesn't help in fluid layout design. DIP tries to make sure things will looks the same size across different screen density. (imagine the concept of Point in typography)

Without your code and/or screenshot of what happen, it is hard to judge what happens to your program, but 22dip text size is possibly one of the reason which:

1. 22dip text in HDPI will become: 22 * 240 / 160 = 33 pixel
2. 22dip text in LDPI will become: 22 * 120 / 160 = 16.5 pixel

If your setting on QVGA is HDPI, then it is actually 33 pixel tall for a letter, which consumes more than 1/10 of the screen height.

By the way, your 16:9 wide screen (vertical) may fit everything in one screen without scroll, while QVGA is only 3:2 screen, even though everything is in proportion, something would be hidden away for sure.

Comment: So would a simple solution around it be to set text to dp rather than dip?

Comment: And how would I go about making sure a 3:2 phone would be formatted in proportion to a 16:9 phone?

Comment: Actually no good solution to this. And they should behave different. You need more stuff(function) as an interface on your desktop, but less in SmartPhones, even less in a device like iPod Nano, right? You can develop different layout according to different DPI devices. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: So I should just accept that really small phones will simply not display my app as it should be?  Will the parts that are clipped off be hidden, not to be accessed or is a sctollview a good option?

Comment: Again, it depends on what kind of interface you are after. E.g. For preference screen, scrolling of the whole stuff is alright, but for a dialer, it's not, you need to keep a part showing (like 'dial' button) in the screen. But I think keeping the `look` varies across device is acceptable/unavoidable, but the functions should remain consistent.